# Laravel display a foreach loop twice in one?

Tags: php, laravel, date, foreach

I have a table:

| name | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2020 | 2021 |
| Adam | 2022 | 2023 |
| Peter | 2024 | 2025 |

I would like to display every date values in a single record.

This is the result I would like to have is:

```
John  2020
John  2021
Adam  2022
Adam  2023
Peter 2024
Peter 2025
```

How to write a loop for this in Laravel?

### UPDATE

I would like to sort the results by desc. How to do that?

Comment: We'd need to see the code that produced the table to begin with...

Comment: I would like to sort the results, so writing like what Quiet Molly suggested is not good.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is rather preety simple, it really depends from Your Model

```
@foreach ($records as $record)
$record->name + " " + $record->date1
$record->name + " " + $record->date2
@endforeach
```

If this isnt what You are looking for, then please try providing more data and ask better question :c